# ReadTheDocs: Publishing Pre-Built HTML Pages to ReadTheDocs

Tags: html, documentation, read-the-docs, pdoc

I was trying to create documentation from python doc strings, and found pdoc. If you don't know, it creates html documentation from python doc strings. Since it generates `.html` files and not `.rst`, how do I publish those to ReadTheDocs or generate `.rst` files using pdoc?

Quick sidenote: I don't want to use sphinx since 1) the theme pdoc has is pretty cool and 2) I don't know how to generate documentation from docstrings using sphinx (all the tutorials I looked at didn't help).

Comment: Doesn't look like [ReadTheDocs supports prebuilt HTML](https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues/1083). Maybe you could host your project's docs on [GitHub pages](https://pages.github.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the Docs released a beta feature some time ago that allows you to completely override the build process. This means that you can execute custom commands (e.g. `pdoc`) and output all the HTML to a particular directory (`_readthedocs/html`). Once the build is finished, Read the Docs will publish the content of that directory.

Check out the documentation at https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/build-customization.html#override-the-build-process

Answer (score 1):

Manuel's answer is right and helpful, though the operation to override the build process is a beta feature.

I built my html docs using local tools and moved html files into a folder, e.g., `pre_built_html/`.

And the `.readthedocs.yaml` file is like:

```
version: 2

build:
    os: ubuntu-20.04
    tools:
      python: "3.8"
    commands: 
      - mkdir --parents _readthedocs/html/
      - cp --recursive pre_built_html/* _readthedocs/html/
```

By the way, i also removed the original `docs` folder.